# Overshoot interpolator animation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

In android, we have overshoot interpolator for animation using Object animator which overshoots the end value of animation and then comes back to end value. Is there any alternative for flutter like in gif below.

[image: Overshoot interpolator]

Comment: did you check `Curves` class (or `Curve` / `Cubic`)?

Comment: yes, but none of curves gives desired effect as overshoot interpolator though.

Comment: see `Curves#elasticOut` see [this](https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/animation/curve_elastic_out.mp4)

Comment: It works though. How did I miss it though. :D. Guess I did not check all the curves. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to @pskink help, Similar behaviour of overshoot interpolator is Curves.elasticOut. As I wanted to control oscillation too I used ElasticOutCurve() curve. below code solved the problem.

```
     _clockWiseRotationAnimation =
    Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 2 * pi).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: ElasticOutCurve(1.0)));
```